# What kind of port is the USB port?

Tags: serial-port, usb, serial-communication

I am developing a serial port communication java-J2ME-J2SE application. There is a mobile phone and a computer ( running Windows XP ). These two machines are communicating through the phone mobile's cable. And the phone mobile's cable is a USB cable. So what is the type of the port : is it COM1 or something else ?
I looked the device manager and I found that the mobile phone ( Alcatel OT-806D ) is in port COM4. Here is a captured image of the device manager:

[image]

Comment: Aside from a vendor specific USB interface, typically the phone uses USB + a virtual serial port that behaves like a physical port, does the phone present itself as a modem?

Comment: how to know if the phone presents itself as a modem ?

Comment: see if its in phone & modems in control panel, click add to autodetect

Comment: it is not in `phone&modems` in control panel. Even though I clicked the add button under the `Modems` tab then windows didn't find it!

Answer (score 1):

An USB port is a kind of serial port that computers and devices can use to communicate. It defines the connectors and cables, as well as the physical and link layer protocols that devices must use to communicate over USB. In this sense, it's similar to Ethernet, Firewire or other communication protocols.

At a physical level, USB is a serial protocol, meaning that bits are sent in a serial fashion. Old serial RS-232 ports (traditionally named COMx under Windows) are not related to modern USB architecture. Old serial ports used a simpler and slower communication protocol (RS-232) that was usually handled by a family of chips called [UART](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_asynchronous_receiver/transmitter)s, whereas USB communication requires more complex hardware.

So, the physical and link-layer characteristics of these two protocols are very different. While both are serial protocols, USB allows for several devices to share the same bus (traditional serial ports don't) and communication speed is much higher in USB. Error detection and correction, flow control and other data transfer concerns are better handled in USB.

COM ports are a Windows abstraction to represent any communication port. In other operating systems other names are used. In Linux, the COM1 port is represented by the device /dev/ttyS0.

Note that this is no more than an abstraction. It is possible (and often done) to use serial ports that are not using the traditional, physical, serial port. In fact, you can create operating system drivers that provide serial ports that are in fact communicating over Ethernet, USB, IP or any other communication layer. The COM port at operating system level is no more than an abstraction to represent a communications port.

Mobile phones offer a variety of services through their USB port. This often includes raw serial communication (which you can use in your application), but in many other cases the USB port provides other "profiles" (usb mass storage, headphones, or whatever). All those profiles are standarized so you can plug your phone to a computer and establish a "serial communication" channel, among other things, without having to code communication drivers for the computer or the phone.

So, to answer your question, no, an USB port is not a COM port. It is an USB port. You can use it for serial communications, but you can also use it for other things.

Answer (score 1):

USB means Universal Serial Bus. Generally all os the USB connections on PC will be linked on the same bus. All devices connected to the bus are assigned virtual port numbers. These port numbers will change depending on what is connected to the bus.

However, you won't be communicating with the phone directly but with any driver that is installed for it, unless you're writing the driver itself.

Some phones are not controllable in any way, others may appear as a modem, because that is the functionality that their manufacturer has assigned them through the drive.

My current phone installs as a device in itself (for use with a manufacturers piece of software), a modem and a storage device.

Have a look [here](http://www.developerfusion.com/article/84338/making-usb-c-friendly/) for some more information.

Comment: When I attach the cable into the PC then there are three choices displayed on the phone mobile's screen : mass storage, webcam or com port. And I choose `com port`. So what is the port in this situation ?

Comment: It will most likely be a virtual serial com port. Have a look in Device Manager it should be listed  under Ports. I've added a link to my answer.

Comment: So why is it impossible to communicate the J2ME app and the J2SE app ?

Answer (score 0):

um, depends what you mean by "type of port".  I think you want to know the name of the port, but what you really need to know is what protocol your phone will understand.

You need to know what protocol (if any) the phone can communicate with over USB.  Just because you can connect the phone to a USB cable doesn't mean that you can control the phone.  This depends on the phone.  Not all phones are built to understand the same protocols.

Also, USB is a serial bus because it transmits data serially on a single line (as opposed to transmitting in parallel over multiple lines), but it doesn't (necessarily) use the same RS-232 protocol as a computer's serial port.  If you had a RS-232 device connected to a USB port, then you would connect to it using COM1 (or COM2 or COM3, your operating system assigns this port name).